# How can we refresh an array displayed in an HTML element after an item is pushed to it?

Tags: javascript, arrays

This file is a simple to do list generator. it starts with three sample items being displayed in a div from a JS array. onclick of button one "push" a prompt comes up and whatever the user adds gets added to the array in JS. this works fine as per the console. the second button "shift" pulls the first item off the list (in traditional to do list style) as the user does one item at a time.the push and shift button both run corresponding JS functions which do the work perfectly. in the console the array is updated each time wither is used.

my question: how do i get the div to refresh the array "toDoListJoined" once a modification is made to the array "toDoList" thru the buttons???

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">

 <head>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <title>JavaScript To Do List</title>
 </head>


 <body id="home">
   <button id="push" onclick="pushPrompt()">Add something to the end of your list</button>
   <button id="shift" onclick="shiftIt()">Remove the first item from your list</button>


 <p id="listPlace">
 <!--Here's where the magic happens-->
 </p>

 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
   let toDoList = ["sample item 1", "sample item 2", "sample item 3"];
   let toDoListJoined = toDoList.join("<br>");
   let addItem = "";

document.getElementById("listPlace").innerHTML = toDoListJoined;

function pushPrompt() {
  addItem = prompt("What is the item you want to add to your list?", "Sample item");
  toDoList.push(addItem);
}

function shiftIt() {
  toDoList.shift();
}
 </script>

 </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a new method so that the html is updated:

```
//create a new method on the Array to push the item and update the HTML. 
toDoList.pushAndUpdate= function(item) {
    //push the item into the array using the prototype push method.
    Array.prototype.push.call(this, item);
    //update the html of my element. 
    document.getElementById("listPlace").innerHTML= this.join("<br>");
}
```

Comment: This is just bad advice. An array is just an array, you shouldn't pretend it as a class and override its native properties.

Comment: Would it be better to declare a new method called `pushAndUpdate` using the same idea?

Comment: That would be better, but if we are doing it properly, I would at least create an object with methods to hold the state and functions to perform updates.

Comment: It would be interesting to see your solution.

Comment: Here's example of what I was talking about: https://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/8oLjjsfc/ Of course the best way would be to create a complete `Todos` class but that would be an overkill for this example.

Comment: We can also use popular frameworks to handle the state updates for us: https://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/75ua9nms/ (ReactJS)

Comment: Ah. I understand.  My question would be why use an object to hold the state of the array? I would think that while more readable,  this lessens maintainability. What if in the future I want to call `Array.indexOf` or `Array.forEach` etc? I thought the whole concept of prototyping was to allow the developer to do exactly what I have done.  P.S. I agree that I shouldn't have overridden the `push` method.

Comment: Technically we are using an object to hold the state of the Todo List. The array is just a container that our `TodoList` object uses to store the data. Using an object is a good idea because we view the Todo List as a whole: we can add methods and properties that do not depend on variables in the outerscope. The concept of OOP is that you should not even call `Array.indexOf` or `Array.forEach` at all outside the object. In fact, you shouldn't even concern how the container is implemented - it can be a list, an array or even a tree, but it doesn't matter to functions outside of the object.

Comment: guys i appreciate your input, ive been reviewing your examples, and the answer for a few days now. 

S. Walker: in the scope of this example i am not worried about forcing class properties on an array. as long as it functions, but i cant seem to get it to work with your code. can you elaborate?

Derek, i noticed you're using babel and jsx, and other frameworks. I'm trying to do this purely in JS. there has to be a way to update the array contents into a <p> element. is there any type of language i can use to simply refresh the <p>?

Comment: @sap, are you getting an error when using my code? Are you calling `pushAndUpdate` instead of `push`?

Comment: i am getting an error. yes im calling pushAndUpdate

"TypeError: this.prototype is undefined" <-from console

what advantage does the new method give logically since were just transferring data? the only logical difference i see is that we are using prototype method in your new method. this.push is basically toDoList.push and this.join  is basically toDoList.join. again the only change is the use of prototype.

im a rookie, and i really appreciate your help, keep this question in that context.

Comment: You are correct,  my code is wrong. I will correct it. I should've used `Array.prototype.push.call(this, item);` instead of `this.prototype.push`. Also, your correct again, all my function does it create a single call so that you may push the item into the correct array and then it will refresh the HTML. Is that not what you wanted?

Comment: And no, I didn't not see the shift operation. You would need to do the same type of thing that I did with the push method.

Comment: works like a charm, i think im going to put he line

"Array.prototype.push.call(this, item);"

in with the individual 2 functions. 

i've marked it correct. thanks!!